# Advanced Custom Fields Plugin hide blank field entries

Tags: php, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I have some fields which I only wish to show if the fields are not blank.
My code so far…

```
<a href="<?php the_field('field_link'); ?>">
<img src="<?php the_field('field_image'); ?>"></a>
```

This works fine if someone has entered a value for both the link and image.
Is it possible to not display anything if the fields are blank?

I have tried various configurations to make this work with my above code and can’t get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're running PHP, it's as simple as wrapping all of that within a PHP if-block:

```
<?php if( get_field('field_link') && get_field('field_image') ): ?>
    <a href="<?php the_field('field_link'); ?>">
    <img src="<?php the_field('field_image'); ?>"></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also, if you're unfamiliar, the above uses PHP's [Alternative Syntax for control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

**Edit:** I understand now this is using the actual plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started/code-examples/) and updated my code.

Comment: This doesn't work. When I apply it to my code, I just get a text output of the URL...It isn't showing <a href="http://whatever"> in the code but shows "http://whatever" - no href code. Any ideas?

Comment: see my updated code at end of original question using your example. It just outputs text - no linked image (and no image at all).

Comment: Sorry I realized we weren't actually `echo'ing` the strings passed back from `the_field()`. I assume this is the case, and updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately same thing happens. Just outputs text url with no link or no image. hmmm. When I view the code, it just outputs the link in inverted commas. No image at all and no href etc.

Comment: Can you paste the result (outputted) HTML code here within grave (`) marks?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52623/discussion-between-laughdonor-and-lowercase)